# Append image to table from ajax result laravel

Tags: php, ajax, append, laravel-5.8

I am tring to append an image to table but whenever I give src path , it doesnt display any result.

```
if(data ){
          txt += '<tr><td>'+data.groupname[i].group_name+'</td><td class="text-right"><img class="remove" src="{{asset('admin/images/icn_close.png')}}" alt="" /><img class="drag-handle" src="{{asset('admin/images/drag-handle.png')}}" alt=""></td></tr>';
          }
if(txt != ""){
          $("#table").append(txt);
            }
```

I want to display the image in public/admin/images folder. If I remove the code of image from the above I get the rest of the result.

Comment: If the curly braces are in JS, they won't be parsed. Check the DOM and see what the `src` attribute shows.

Comment: How can I include laravel image path to src?

Comment: You could setup a accessor and then call that in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use asset inside javascript
so you can retrieve the path with your response

```
if(data ){
          txt += '<tr><td>'+data.groupname[i].group_name+'</td><td class="text-right"><img class="drag-handle" src="'+data.img_url+'" alt=""></td></tr>';
          }
```

and in your method in controller

```
public function get(){
return reponse()->json(['img_url'=>asset('admin/images/icn_close.png'),'groupname'=>$groupname]);
}
```

Comment: What about: `src="{{asset('admin/images/drag-handle.png')}}"`?

Comment: I updated my answer ,remove src.
Review it plz!
I hope the answer help you!

Comment: In my controller , I gave like this: 'img_url'=> asset('admin/images/icn_close.png'). Giving curly braces directly didn't work for me. A

Comment: `'src="+data.img_url+"'` - Is wrong, the string is wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Will be src="'+data.img_url+'"  @Script47

Comment: May you donnot have this directory @Rose or write public before admin

Comment: I think there is no need of {{ }} curly braces for url path in controller.

Comment: @mohamed hassan: your answer gave me the solution. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes ,you donn't need it, 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can also parsed public image in Java script using the asset.

In the code there is an error while calling the image using the asset. Better to assign in a variable, then use it will work.

like.

```
 var icn_close="{{ asset('admin/images/icn_close.png') }}";
   var drag_handle="{{ asset('admin/images/drag-handle.png') }}";
   var group_name = data.groupname[i].group_name;
   txt += '<tr><td>'+group_name+'</td><td class="text-right"><img class="remove" src="'+icn_close+'" alt="" /><img class="drag-handle" src="'+drag_handle+'" alt=""></td></tr>';
```